# Can't run assembly language program in Visual Studio 2019- Unable to start program, system cant find file specified

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

im trying to run this program in VS2019 but the it keep pop out  "Unable to start program, system cant find file specified". i see my lecturer run this smoothly but when on me it just doesnt work. can it be because of the setup?

'''
`INCLUDE Irvine32.inc`
`.code`
`main PROC`
`mov    eax,10000h ; EAX=10000h`
`add eax,10000h; EAX=50000h`
`sub    eax,20000h; EAX=30000h`

`call DumpRegs`
`exit`
`main ENDP`
`END main`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you don't have the assembly source file included in the build. Right click on the source file name, then properties, then set "excluded from build" to no. Then set up custom build step. For example, if source file name is x.asm, for debug build:

```
command line: ml /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\x.obj x.asm
output: $(OutDir)\x.obj
```

For release, the same, except for the Zi:

```
command line: ml /c Fo$(OutDir)\x.obj x.asm
output: $(OutDir)\x.obj
```

I usually create an empty project, and once the directory is created, copy the source file(s) into the directory, then "add existing item" to the project, then do the above steps to get the assembler commands to work.

In some cases, VS2019 will default to building assembly source files when first installed, but if it doesn't I haven't found a way to get it to happen without manually setting up a custom build step.

Comment: Why not simply add MASM to the build customizations and then add the assembly files to the project? Build customizations in VS have had support for MASM/ML for the last decade. Right click the project, select `build dependencies` on the menu then `build customizations` then put a check next to MASM targets. If you added the ASM files before enabling the MASM build customization you can go in after and change each of the files so they have item type `Microsoft Macro Assembler` and then ensure they are not excluded from the build process.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - I've had issues trying to do that with older versions of VS. Note that VS2010 is the last version that can run on Win XP or Win XP X64. I'm running VS2015 on Win 7 and VS2019 on Win 10. I assume building a 64 bit program would use ML64 for MASM files?

Comment: Yes, the MASM build customization will use ML64 or ML depending on the target platform. Recent VS also have support for the ARM assembler build customization for that platform as well. In this case the OP says they are using VS2019 and given the code I assume he targeting x86. VS2015 definitely has support for the MASM build customization. I've used this feature for many years.

Answer (score 1):

My Avast anti-virus software moved the file to the Quarantine before the IDE could run it.
It was giving me the same error "Can't find file".

I paused the avast software and the program started working just fine.